# Is there a notation for polynomial division?

Tags: notation

In number theory, for any given integers $a,b$, $a|b$ is defined to mean $a \text{ divides } b$.

What about polynomials division? Or any ring?
Is $f(X)|g(X)$ generally used to mean $f(X) \text{ divides } g(X)$?

Comment: Yes, $f(X)\mid g(X)$ or $f\mid g$.

Comment: Just, I would call it *divisibility*. I believe *division* is usually reserved for Euclidean division, when it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: We even use this notion with the same meaning between to elements of a semigroup.